# How to exempt an element from a keyframes animation?

Tags: html, css

I am using a keyframe to fade a `<nav>` in. However I want one `li` not to fade in. Anyone know how?

First here is the CSS:

```
nav{   
    -webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s; 
    -moz-animation: fadein 0.5s; 
    -ms-animation: fadein 0.5s; 
     -o-animation: fadein 0.5s; 
        animation: fadein 0.5s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
 }

@-ms-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

@-o-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<nav id="nav">
    <ul>
    <li id="menuIcon"> <img src="menuIcon.svg" alt="q" onclick="showMenu()">  </li>
        <li id="aboutList"> <a href="#about"> About </a> </li>
        <li id="openingList"> <a href="#opening"> When </a> </li>
        <li id="whereList"> <a href="#where"> Where </a> </li>      
    </ul>   
</nav>
```

Comment: Do you want the li to appear without the animation or do you want it to not appear at all?

Comment: *I want one li not to fade in* - Which one?

Comment: Appear with out Animation please

Comment: Opacity of the parent will always affect the children as well...what you want is not possible in your current form other than applying the animation to all of the `li` elements **except** the one to remain.